# How to deal with an incomplete comment after the 5 minute limit hits? Delete it or leave it?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that you can only edit your on comments within 5 minutes after posting them. By accident I left an half-baked comment but when editing it, it exceeded the 5 minute limit. Instead I deleted my comment and added the corrected version instead.

I guess proofreading the comment before posting it, is a good idea to avoid the situation. But when it happens, is it acceptable to delete it and repost it when there was no activity yet? Or is it recommended to leave old comment and post the new one as "Upps, what I really meant was..."?

Comment: Delete and re-comment is my MO.  But most mistakes in comments are not that big a deal.  (Most comments are not  a big deal to begin with.)

Comment: All you have to d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing, since there was no activity yet.

If it were the middle of a conversation and people had responded to you, delete and repost would have been confusing for other users, but that's not the case here.

[When you comment, the person whose post you're commenting on gets a red notification in the top left hand corner. (Also if you @username notify them). If you delete and repost there's a very small chance the double notification irritated them, but I don't think you should worry at all about that.]

A single, clear and well-thought through comment is easier for future visitors to follow than "oh and another thing...".

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how badly the fix is needed and who will end up getting pinged. If there is a letter awry on a comment to someone else's answer, I'd say let it be. Feel free to be a perfectionist if you aren't pinging anyone.

On the other hand, if I accidentally mistype "*You have a missing parenthesis on line 3*" as "*Prenthsi 3 lyne not*", I'll go for a delete->repost. In general, if your flawed comment is incomprehensible and is just adding noise to the page, correcting it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, you should delete and rewrite it. You may risk that someone answers to it before you repost it, but that's an acceptable risk (it's an exaggeration to call it risk).